# Netbeans Tomcat Output Window has no console input

Tags: java, tomcat, input, netbeans, console

I'm starting Tomcat in Netbeans via the Services tab and see the output window as usual.

The problem is, I have a web application which needs a password to be typed in at runtime to be sent via console to the application.

I found this bug report (a bit old): https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47708&x=17&y=7 but i can't figure out whether it should be solved now or what to configure to get it run.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want your application to start by only authenticate person?

Comment: Did you try it without Netbeans but Tomcat only? I guess Tomcat does not accept `stdin`.

Comment: Whether I need stdin or not is another discussion. This works fine in Eclipse and in standalone Tomcat deployments. Only Netbeans seems to lack support for stdin in its output window.